# How can I get Delphi to wait for a form to close before continuing to execute code in another form?

Tags: forms, delphi, modal-dialog

My program has to search through a CSV file line by line and if a unique item is found, another form needs to be opened asking the user for more information on this item to store in a file before continuing to search the CSV file. I have browsed around looking for an answer and the only thing that I can find is showmodal which closes the pop-up form after it's finished. I need to keep the form open in case there is another unique item. I have also tried having a repeat, until loop which repeats until the value of a certain variable is changed by the pop-up form, allowing the program to continue when the pop-up form is hidden. This, however, does not seem to work and causes the pop-up form to be blank and unusable. Help please!

Comment: Put the long running code in a thread.

Comment: Is the user's input critical to continuing the processing and is future processing dependent upon previous user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> another form needs to be opened asking the user for more information on this item to store in a file before continuing

This is what called "Modal Window"

Hence it is displayed by `.ShowModal` method.

```
if ItemFound then begin
  user_info := false;
  user_prompt := CreateMessageDialog(... 'answer me!' );
  try
    user_choice := user_prompt.ShowModal();
    if IsPositiveResult(user_choice) then begin
       user_Var_1 := Trim(user_prompt.Edit1.Text);
       user_Var_2 := user_prompt.ListBox1.ItemIndex;
       ....
       user_info := True;
    end. 
  finally
    user_prompt.Destroy;
  end;
  if user_info then begin
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Read manuals:

- http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TCustomForm_ShowModal.html
- http://delphi.about.com/library/rtl/blrtlCreateMessageDialog.htm
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Dialogs.CreateMessageDialog

Comment: The "Modal" itself Actually stores the item(s) in the file and is a fairly complex form. It can't just be a message dialog. How do I use the modal method but be able to use this form again?

Comment: do not free/dispose/release the form after ShowModal, then you can change all the properties you need to change and ShowModal again

Comment: also if the form has OnClose event ensure it chooses "hide" action instead of destroying itself